# Where to post a question about Algorithm-Copyright?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I posted a question (which is deleted now) on Stack Overflow, but it got closed as off-topic, but nobody answered my comment about the appropriate Stack Exchange site.

Where should I post a question about the copyright/license of a random number generator?

Comment: Link to the question? This depends on the question.

Comment: @djechlin [Lehmer RNG - Copyright/License](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23496333/lehmer-rng-copyright-license)

Comment: I don't think we have a site (or even an Area 51 proposal) where this question would fit.

Comment: After i did some hours of research, I found the answer to my original question. Since this question apparently can't be answered, should I delete it or wait for somebody to answer "There is no such SE site." and accept that comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no Stack Exchange site for legal issues.

That said, your specific question *might* be on topic for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).  While [most legal questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) are closed as off-topic there, [software licensing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/licensing) *is* explicitly on topic.

(Oh, and the answer?  [Algorithms can't be copyrighted](http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ61.pdf), although, in some jurisdictions, [they can be patented](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32482/can-an-algorithm-be-patented).  Copyright only protects a specific *implementation* of an algorithm, as a creative work.  If you've written your own implementation, rather than copying someone else's code, you should be safe as far as copyright is concerned.)

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/what-is-the-difference-between-software-licensing-and-copyright